"PublishStatus" Field in Knowledge__kav Object Value change is not getting captured by Flow or Trigger
"PublishStatus" Field in Knowledge__kav Object Value change is not getting captured by Flow or Trigger when any knowledge article record shifts from Draft to Online (Published). Can anyone plz help in order to resolve issue, any help is much appreciated.
I have created a Flow in order to generate custom notification when knowledge article publish status changed from Draft to Online but Flow is unable to capture the PublishStatus field value change in order to execute further blocks to generate notification.





when you turn on debug log, what do you see for the flow events?

If you read through the documentation.
It says "Actions that change the publication status of a KAV record, such as Publish and Archive, do not fire Apex or flow triggers."
